# Laravel: Validate an array of strings

Tags: laravel

How to validate that fruits from a given `$list` are in the allowed list ?

```
$attributes [
  "fruits" => ['nullable', 'string', 'in:apple,banana,orange'],
];

$list = [
  "fruits" => [
    "apple",
    "orange"
  ]
];

$validator = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($list, $attributes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can validate each item in this array individually:

```
$attributes = [
  "fruits.*" => ['nullable', 'string', Rule::in(['apple','banana','orange'])],
];
```